# SaaS Rails Kit: Redirect after login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, devise

I just started using the SaaS Rails Kit and need some assistance with redirecting my users.

I want to my registered account users to always be taken to my jobs page (jobs/index.html.erb) after successfully logging in at users/sign_up.  Currently when users log in they are always taken to content#index via the routes.rb.  I was hoping to override Devise under devise_for :users, but no matter what I try it doesn't work.

How/where do I override the Devise to take my user to the page of my choice?  Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop something like this into your ApplicationController:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  some_path_to_redirect_to
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I now get the following error: AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Devise::SessionsController#new

Comment: got it to work using the following, thanks: def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      stored_location_for(resource) || clients_path
    end